# Console Input in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

So I am trying to make a text-based game, but I cannot find out in the ibook about Swift made by apple how to get input from the console. I have tried a few ways that I saw on here, but I did not really understand how to use those methods.

Comment: Before you release this text-based game you will have to find some other way for the user to input text. There is no console on the devices.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Console ?

Comment: @68cherries You can use Swift to build Mac applications too. OS X has a terminal.

Comment: In fact, Xcode provides for OSX command-line (console) apps using swift. Not interactively, but it does allow for them.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like there are any input stream facilities in the Swift standard library. But you still have options:

- `import Darwin` and use `scanf` or `getc` or your favorite POSIX level input routine
- `import Foundation` and use `NSInputStream`, `NSScanner` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, only a subset of Darwin is working right now like rand().

Comment: Please come up with a working example to best solve the askers question.